# Reflection get type of FieldInfo object?

Tags: c#, reflection

HI All,
I need to access the class **SomeClass** which is declared has a private field in the Wrapper class, using Reflection so far i have been able to get private field members . How do i cast it back to its original type so that i could access it properties and other members.

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Wrapper wrap = new Wrapper
            {
                SOmeProperty = new SomeClass
                {
                    Number = 007
                }
            };

            Type type = wrap.GetType();
            FieldInfo[] infos = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var item in infos)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    internal class SomeClass
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Wrapper
    {
        private SomeClass _tempSomeObj;

        public SomeClass SOmeProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _tempSomeObj;
            }
            set
            {
                _tempSomeObj = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I dont know if i understand the question correct. You want the type of the private field (backing field)??

Then you could check the FieldType property of the FieldInfo....

like this:

```
internal class Program
{
    #region Methods

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wrap = new Wrapper { SOmeProperty = new SomeClass { Number = 007 } };
        Type type = wrap.GetType();

        FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var fieldInfo in fieldInfos)
        {
            if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(SomeClass))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yap!");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

internal class SomeClass
{
    #region Properties

    public int Number { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

internal class Wrapper
{
    #region Properties

    public SomeClass SOmeProperty { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `PropertyInfo` instead:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Wrapper wrap = new Wrapper
        {
            SOmeProperty = new SomeClass
            {
                Number = 007
            }
        };

        Type type = wrap.GetType();
        PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty("SOmeProperty", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        SomeClass value = (SomeClass)info.GetValue(wrap, null);
        // use `value` variable here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . What i really want to achieve is . Inned to be able to iterate through a classes properties . The class here that i need to be specifed is of type T. So what i really wanted was if i could some how get this class loaded dynamically ? Example : Imagine "SomeClass" is sent as a T parameter so my type will vary firsr i send "SomeClass" then later i send "SomeClass2" and so on irrespective of the class type i need to be able to iterate though its properties . I Need to get this type at runtime and then iterate through its properties ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little fuzzy about what your're trying to do, but you can always GetType() on any object and get its actual run time type and query that for properties field of  some other type for example

```
public void ListPropertiesOfType( object targetObject, Type propertyType ) {
  foreach( var foundProperty in targetObject.GetType( ).GetProperties( ).Where( p => p.PropertyType == propertyType ) ) {
    Console.WriteLine( "Name: {0}, Value: {1}", foundProperty.Name, foundProperty.GetValue( targetObject, null ) );
  }
}

ListPropertiesOfType(new Wrapper(), typeof(SomeClass))
ListPropertiesOfType(new Wrapper(), typeof(SomeOtherClass))
```

If you want to pass in instances of Someclass and SomeClass that is also fine, just use GetType() on the instances to get the type that you can then use to find properties of that type as illustrated above. this works the same way regardless if you make the method generic and pass in "T" or if its non-generic and you pass in "object"