# Access Value of TextSegment by reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

I have an object of type 'System.Windows.Documents.TextSegment' in an object of type Object. The TextSegment-Struct i can not use in my code, because it's internal code of the .net-framework.

What I want to do is, accessing the Start- and End-Property in the object of type TextSegment. I tried it by reflection with the following code:

```
// This object is of type TextSegment
object textSegment = segments[0];
FieldInfo info = textSegment.GetType().GetField("_start", BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | 
   BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance| BindingFlags.Static;
```

Now I don't know how to access the value of the FieldInfo.

I tried it with the following codes:

```
object value1 = info.GetValue(segments[0]);
object value2 = info.GetValue(null);
```

but nothing worked.

How can i get the value of the TextSegment?

Comment: can you try something like the following `var value1 = segments.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault( p => p.Name == yourPropertyName);`

Comment: no, this doesn't work. I get null for value1

Comment: I just realized that you are wanting FieldInfo look at this Stackoverflow posting I was thinking about PropertyInfo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090224/reflection-get-type-of-fieldinfo-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code rings [a bell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15292203/385995) ;)...

You have a typo (missing bracket at the end of the BindingFlags), and of the BindingFlags, you would only need Instance and NonPublic, but I can't find a real issue.

Perhaps you need to provide more code, because I have checked and this works fine for me:

[image]

Have you checked that the value IS in fact not null?

[image]

Comment: I see exact the same as you. But how do i store this? I can't create an object of TextPointer or something else. How do I get the value of Start and End into a property. That's the problem... :(

Comment: I don't quite understand. If value1 shows up in the debugger like that, you already have it, no? Store it in a property of type `object`. Perhaps you need to tell me what you want to do with it after.

Comment: Yes, of course I'm able to store the Start-Property into a property of type object. But I need to access the concret value of Start. This is the problem. If I store it into an object I'm not able to access properties.

Comment: DocumentSequenceTextPointer is an internal sealed class, you will not be able to store in in a type that will allow you to easily access its properties. If you need those properties, you must resort to reflection again: `value1.GetType().GetProperty/GetField...`